Cannot install py7zr package using Python 3.12
After running vscode in terminal, python 7z.py error appears:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py7zr'
Reinstalling the library didn't help.
I am using Python 3.12.2
I tried:
pip install py7zr
Please help me solve this problem

Try this py -m pip install py7zr

You need to provide more details (e.g. output of the commands you ran) so that other can help you.
Check whether you are installing the py7zr in the right virtual environment.
